# Sailsjs external module not working in service

Tags: rest, express, sails.js

I'm using restler (https://github.com/danwrong/restler) to make api calls from an external source. In Sailsjs, from what I understand, helper functions are called services. I put the restler code for get, post, etc in their own services so I wouldn't repeat myself with the same code over and over again. However, the restler functions that worked fine in my controller no longer worked in the service. For instance:

```
//api/services/myService.js
module.export{
        httpGet: function(){
        var rest = require('restler');
        rest.get('http://google.com').on('complete', function(result) {
        if (result instanceof Error) {
            console.log('Error:', result.message);
            this.retry(5000); // try again after 5 sec
        } else {
            console.log(result);
        }
        });

    }

}
```

I know my service is being used correctly; I've tried returning a variable from the service to double check:

```
        httpGet: function(){
        var check = null;
        var rest = require('restler');
        rest.get('http://google.com').on('complete', function(result) {
        if (result instanceof Error) {
            check = false;
            console.log('Error:', result.message);
            this.retry(5000); // try again after 5 sec
        } else {
            console.log(result);
            check = true;
        }
        });
        return check;
        //in the controller,  myService.httpGet() returns null, not true or false
    }
```

Any help would be very appreciated. Salisjs v0.12.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to make the service to accept a callback.

```
//api/services/myService.js
module.exports = {
        httpGet: function(callback){
        var rest = require('restler');
        rest.get('http://google.com').on('complete', function(result) {
        if (result instanceof Error) {
            console.log('Error:', result.message);
            return callback(result, null)
            //this.retry(5000); // try again after 5 sec
        } else {
            console.log(result);
            return callback(null, result)
        }
        });

    }

}
```

Then from your controller pass a callback when calling the service

```
myService.httpGet(function callback(err, result){
    // handle error 

   // use result

})
```

Moreover regarding your question, you are returning `return check;` from service early with the value `null` you assigned to it.

PS: You can use promises instead of using callback( [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com) )

Comment: One small thing. I think there should be ```module.exports = {```. Otherwise there is syntax error.

Comment: @Bonanza yes. indeed. It was a typo. :)

Comment: Thanks. I fundamentally misunderstood callbacks; I was trying to return a value in the function.

Answer (score 0):

You should export the `httpGet` function as a property of the module object. Basically, you've got a "small" typo. Instead of this:

```
module.export{
        httpGet: function(){
```

you should have this:

```
module.exports = {
        httpGet: function(){
```

And also, if you want to return the result, add a `callback`:

```
module.exports = {
        httpGet: function(callback){
                 ... 
                 if (result instanceof Error) {
                    console.log('Error:', result.message);
                    return callback(result, null)
                 } else {
                    console.log(result);
                    return callback(null, result)
                 }
                    ...
```

... or use Promises.